# Is it possible to call navigator from Native Android with React Native?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, react-native, navigator

The desired outcome is to create an app with a Drawer just like the native android which opens the screens which are react-native driven. I was already able to present one react-native screen by creating an Drawer Android Project with Android Studio and then creating a frame layout to hold the content like so:

`FrameLayout contentHolder = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.content_holder);
 contentHolder.addView(mReactRootView);`

Now what I want to know is: how to navigate through the screens when the user clicks one of the drawer's item. Is it possible to do with react navigator or I should just repeat this code with a different file (eg: `secondPage.android.js` and `secondPage.android.bundle`) -> (it doesn't seem like the right thing to do):

```
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
  .setApplication(getApplication())
  .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
  .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
  .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
  .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
  .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
  .build();
```